# Comment traduire le « no-nonsense [Nom] » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

> Single assignment for the no-nonsense [prénom nom (un arbitre)].

Le contexte c'est le commentaire sportif, on parle d'un arbitre d'un des match d'un tournoi. L'adjectif « [no-nonsense](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/no%20nonsense) » c'est l'aspect *pratique* ([1](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/no-nonsense/597901), [2](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-nonsense)) l'absence de distraction, chez la personne ou la qualité consistant à ne pas être particulier pourrait-on dire.

Comment exprime-t-on cette qualité et comment traduit-on le *no-nonsense* [nom de personne] dans l'exemple ; connaître la profession de la personne est-il utile, y a-t-il une seule traduction possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Quelques suggestions, qui ne sont pas des adjectifs, mais je propose :

- qui ne fait pas de chichis
- à la tête froide

Sinon, l'adjectif "pragmatique" véhicule en partie cette notion, bien que peut-être de manière un peu plus 'terne'.

Comment: Peut-on dire/employer _sans chichis_ directement devant le nom ? cc @jlliagre

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Pas que je sache.

Answer (score 0):

J'aime bien *qui ne fait pas de chichis* de @Mogu +1

Voici quelques autres qualificatifs :

- sobre
- sage
- de bon sens
- mesuré
- raisonnable

Answer (score 0):

[Wordreference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/no-nonsense) donne « terre à terre ; réfléchi, posé » et dans leur forum on trouve « qui ne tourne pas autour du pot ; efficace » etc. ; [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/no-nonsense) en ligne suggère « qui va droit au but ».

Avec la phrase de la question, il est plus difficile d'employer certains de ces mots (ou la relative) en épithète (manque d'euphonie) quoique *efficace* ainsi que d'autres [suggestions](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44439/26366) soient pas mal dans ce contexte. En se rapportant à la définition « very serious about doing things in a direct and efficient way without any foolishness or nonsense », on peut cibler en amont (*very serious about...*) en étant moins précis et chosir « (bien/très) [sérieux](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9rieux) » ; je trouve que ça se prononce mieux avec un adverbe :

> Seule tâche/prestation de la soirée pour le bien/très sérieux Joe X.